# HAProxy: forward frontend request to external backend server

Tags: haproxy

I want to forward requests to an external server when someone requests a subdirectory in my domain.

I've got the following config but I'm still getting a 503:

```
resolvers dns
  nameserver google-1 8.8.8.8:53
  nameserver google-2 8.8.4.4:53
  hold valid 1s

frontend http-in
  maxconn 1048576

  bind *:80
  bind *:443 ssl crt /path/to/ssl

  redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

  acl is_dashboard_uri path_beg /dashboard
  use_backend surge if is_dashboard_uri

  default_backend servers

backend surge
  option forwardfor
  balance leastconn
  server surge my-path.surge.sh:443 check resolvers dns
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have access to both the DNS server and the backend path.

Edit: here's the logs:

```
Jun 12 21:32:05 ion-matchmaker-load-balancer haproxy[12612]: 73.70.169.76:54627 [12/Jun/2018:21:32:05.127] http-in~ surge/surge 0/59/-1/-1/+79 503 +213 - - sC-- 4/4/0/0/3 0/0 "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1"
```

Comment: error is coming ->  unknown keyword 'resolvers'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sC--` in the logs occurs when the backend is not able to fulfill a request in a timely manner.

> The "timeout connect" stroke before a connection to the server could
>             complete. When this happens in HTTP mode, the status code is likely a
>             503 or 504 here.

I increased the timeout on the backend and it gave the server enough time to process the request.

```
backend surge
  timeout connect 5000
```